How do people with NPD interact with the criminal justice system?
Criminology classes surprisingly only have vague details about personality disordered people and how they react to the criminal justice systems.
Some of the details that they claimed were universal to people with ASPD and NPDthat become involved with the law were "remorse about getting caught and the consequences rather than remorse about their actions".
Do they believe that if they were in a situation where they got involved with the law , they would fear and grieve over the consequences more than the harm caused ?
Does threat of punishment deter them ?
https://illinoislawrev.web.illinois.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Tinetti.pdf
